# Please recommend a good D-Bus tutorial (Linux C GTK+)

Tags: c, linux, gtk, dbus

Yes, I have done a search yet found only partly working stuff. It seems to be a real maze. E.g.:

- Why do they even use `g_main_loop_run()`? Is it really necessary when the GTK+ program has already entered the main loop by `gtk_main()`?
- How should the path, the interface name and the signal name look like when invoking such functions like `dbus_bus_request_name()`, `dbus_message_new_signal()`, `dbus_bus_add_match()`, `dbus_message_is_signal()` ...?
- How afterwards should the names be correctly set in the `/etc/dbus-1/system.conf` file to even allow the program to use the the D-Bus interface? Surprisingly all tutorials I found simply forget to mention  at all you need to edit it.
- How the messages could be caught asynchronously? Should it be done somehow like in a separate thread?

Please recommend any good GTK+ D-Bus example which could help to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

`gtk_main` is calling  `g_main_loop_run()`, you should look into file [gtk/gtkmain.c](http://www.koders.com/c/fidEE9B81D3E82CDF39831A62B7D535EA7494A7A898.aspx) to find out.

Googling for `dbug_bus_request_name` gives several examples, notably [dbus-example.c](http://www.matthew.ath.cx/projects.git/dbus-example.c)

And you should read a good [gtk tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/) to have an idea of what signals and slots mean in the context of Gtk.

Googling for `d-bus tutorial` gives [this dbus tutorial](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html)

At last, a good idea is to find and study the source code of the relevant free software. GtkApplication examples are calling dbus code.